How to dynamically increase -in-real-time- the Azure NetApp Files volume?
It cannot be done based on monitoring alerts, since the ThroughputLimitReached metric is only updating in every 5 minutes. That is not real-time.
Question: is there an automated way to increase an ANF volumes throughput?

To dynamically increase the Azure NetApp Files volume throughput, you can adjust the volume's QoS setting. Increasing the QoS setting manually or increasing the volume size automatically increases the allowable volume throughput.
Note-  As per MS doc, the change in throughput limit does not impact volume access. You can adjust the quota during an active I/O transaction against a volume also volume quota can never be decreased below the amount of logical data that is stored in the volume. Checkout "Automatic QoS volume quota and throughput"
References:
Performance considerations for Azure NetApp Files
Dynamically change the service level of an Azure NetApp Files volume
Can it be automated? I don't think so. But you can check out Azure Function to automate (schedule) this to run periodically based on custom logic (e.g. time-based, periodic checks, or custom metrics).
